# Does a character keep their class levels when changing in to a ghoul/ghast?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead

When someone dies from Ghoul fever, and they are a 6th level fighter, do they turn in to a Ghast with 6 levels of fighter? Or do they just become a 6HD ghast? I know the answer to this in D&D 3.5, but unsure if it has changed in Pathfinder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### They're not a fighter any longer

According to PF SRD, on both the ghoul and ghast description of the fever:

> A humanoid who becomes a ghoul in this way retains none of the abilities it possessed in life.

Therefore unless other spells or foul play are in effect they would be the basic form.